# Set attribute length when exporting features with st_write

Tags: r, attribute-table, sf

I have `sf` features that I have created/manipulated in R that I need to export to shapefile (my client only accepts shapefile format so I cannot use .gpkg or other formats). I have used `st_write` to successfully save the features as a new file, however, the length of each attribute is the maximum length possible. How can I set the **length** for each attribute? The [help](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/sf/versions/0.7-3/topics/st_write) file indicates that this is probably possible but I can't quite figure out how. I'm guessing that is it is in `dataset_options = NULL, layer_options = NULL`.

Example using sample dataset

```
nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))
st_write(nc[,c("AREA", "NAME", "CNTY_ID")], "nc_test2.shp",name=c("area", "name", "ID"))
```

[image]

All the numbers are considered as float/double values with the maximum length and precision and the text values have a length of 80. How can I set the length when doing the export? In SQL, the statement would be something like this:

```
ALTER COLUMN (NAME TYPE CHAR(20), 
        AREA numeric(5, 3), 
        CNTY_ID int(5))
```

Comment: If you can control this it will be via options in GDAL's SHP driver, or other workarounds: https://gdal.org/drv_shapefile.html . Another option is to (re)write the DBF with `foreign::write.dbf` which has a max_nchar arg. You probably can't control the numeric type other than double/integer because R has no 'single' floating point type.

Comment: I'm getting deja-vu here - did someone ask this question recently (in the last month or so) - maybe it was for `sp` and `rgdal` rather than `sf` but possibly some insights there too...

Comment: I am still hoping for an answer to this. @mdsumner Could you expand on your answer? I can't see how to use write dbf with different maximum characters for each column/attribute.